# "Выпендриться"

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы узнать этимологию слова "выпендриваться", "выпендриться".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

выпéндриваться 'выставлять себя напоказ' (в словарях не отражено), видимо, восходит к областному *выпетриватъся, где затем было инфигировано -н-, а -тр- перешло в -др- в условиях экспрессивного употребления. Форма* выпетриваться может быть объяснена из *выпятриваться,* выпятрить(ся), ср. блр. выпетрыць 'выветрить, высушить' [1] и то и другое - из исконного слав. *vy-pętriti, собственно, 'выставить, растянуть, расстелить на приспособлении* pętro. Это последнее означало 'стояк, станина (для растяжки)', представлено достаточно широко в ряде славянских языков и связано этимологически с *pęti,* pьno 'натягивать, напяливать, пялить'.

(Трубачев)
http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/trubachev-65.htm